# Refer to temporary workbook with formula

Tags: function, vba, excel, formula

How would you put this formula `=LEFT(A1,SEARCH("invoice",A1,1)-1)` in VBA, so this formula would go in a temporary workbook cell?

Comment: What is a temporary workbook cell?

Comment: @KimGysen sorry I meant, the formula will  be  in a temporary workbook.

Comment: Are you looking for the syntax to fill in a regular formula in the range of a temporary workbook, or do you have trouble with the search function?

Comment: @KimGysen I had issue with both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
Dim oBook as Excel.workbook 

set oBook = workbooks.add
oBook.sheets(1).range("B1").formula = "=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(""invoice"",A1,1)-1)"

oBook.close
```

Comment: Yes like this, apart that this bit of coding does not work unfortunately it does not work and it comes up with the error:'end of statement'

Comment: @Kim Gysen:  Consider doubling-up on the internal double-quotes

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Thanks for your notification, I edited the answer.

Comment: @KimGysen it still does not work, it comes up with the error 'Run-time error '1004', it's an application defined or object defined error

Comment: @Abi, Dick Kusleika rectified my mistake meanwhile. I added single quotes instead of the double-double quotes as Gary's student mentioned. I was being confused with another language I'm currently working with. Sorry for that!